# Calculate rowSums by varying the selected columns

Tags: r, data.table

Good morning,
I am blocked.

I have the following objects:

```
d1:
    a  b  d e
1:  0 32  0 1
2:  0 40  0 3
3: 23  0  0 2
4: 32  0 32 4
5:  0  0 56 0

w:
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "d"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "b" "e"
```

And I need the sum of the rows, only using the columns contained in words (for each "iteration")

```
    a  b  d e f1 f2 f3
1:  0 32  0 1 32 32 33
2:  0 40  0 3 40 40 43
3: 23  0  0 2 23  0 25
4: 32  0 32 4 32 32 36
5:  0  0 56 0  0 56  0

d1[,f1:=rowSums(.SD),.SDcols=w[[1]]]

d1[,f2:=rowSums(.SD),.SDcols=w[[2]]]

d1[,f3:=rowSums(.SD),.SDcols=w[[3]]]
```

I can not use loops or `lapply`, the loops are very slow and `lapply` is not memory efficient. The real data is a matrix of 1112 rows and 108968 columns (at best) and a list of more than 4 million character vectors.

Thanks!

**data**

```
d1 <- read.table(h=T,strin=F,text=
"a  b  d e
 0 32  0 1
 0 40  0 3
23  0  0 2
32  0 32 4
 0  0 56 0")
data.table::setDT(d1)

w <- list(c("a","b"),c("b","d"),c("a","b","e"))
```

Comment: you can use `fread()` to create d1 directly.

Answer (score 4):

Your statement

> I can not use loops or lapply, the loops are very slow and lapply is not memory efficient.

would mean that you have to type it out manually. Consider using loops efficiently, for example like this:

```
for(i in seq_along(w)) {
  set(d1, i = NULL, j = paste0("f", i), value = rowSums(d1[, w[[i]], with=FALSE]))
}
```

The result is:

```
d1
#    a  b  d e f1 f2 f3
#1:  0 32  0 1 32 32 33
#2:  0 40  0 3 40 40 43
#3: 23  0  0 2 23  0 25
#4: 32  0 32 4 32 32 36
#5:  0  0 56 0  0 56  0
```

As mentioned by @Frank in his comment, it would be appropriate in this case to replace

```
rowSums(d1[, w[[i]], with=FALSE])
```

with

```
Reduce("+", d1[, w[[i]], with=FALSE])
```

since the input is not a matrix (and `rowSums` coerces its input to matrix if it's not already). In effect, this would be a more efficient approach at the cost of not being able to handle NA-entries easily (like it's possible in `rowSums`).

Comment: @Frank, good point, will add that to my answer if you don't mind